# tm struct object confusion

Tags: c, struct

I am a bit confused as to how the tm struct objects are used, if I do;

```
printf("The current date is %d-%d-%d\n", now.tm_mon, now.tm_mday, now.tm_year);
```

My output is;

```
The current date is 11-31-112
```

But when I do;

```
printf("The current date is %d-%d-%d\n", now.tm_mon + 1, now.tm_mday, now.tm_year 
+ 1900);
```

My output is;

```
The current date is 12-31-2012
```

I am a bit confused how the addition of the +1, and +1900 correctly format the output time? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how the values in a tm struct are [defined](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime):

- tm_mon = The number of months since January, in the range 0 to 11.
- tm_year = The number of years since 1900.

I suspect a reason for having the starting year be 1900 was to enable the use of two digit year values, we all saw how well that worked out.

An interesting side note is that 1900 is about the time worldwide [timezones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) became standard, so maybe people figured that was a good a time as any to set the start year. Just speculation though.

Comment: and the reason for month starting at 0 would be to look it up a name in a 0-based array

Comment: Right. Although `tm_mday` starts at 1, not sure why that one is different.

Comment: US-centric, where days of the month don't have names, per se?

Answer (score 4):

From the manpage:

> tm_mon    The number of months since January, in the range 0 to 11.
>
> ```
>    tm_year   The number of years since 1900.
> ```

You may also want to take a look at the `strftime` function for output.